# No se insertan datos en la base de datos

Tags: php

Tengo un archivo de conexión con la base de datos y un hormulario de html que recoge la información, lo estoy intentando ingresar a la base de datos pero no insertan.

```
<?php

        $host="localhost";
        $usuario="id20701976_minencuentro";
        $pass="********";
        $nomdb="id20701976_formularios";

            $conexion=new mysqli($host,$usuario,$pass,$nomdb);

        if ($conexion) {
                echo    "Estamos conectados a la Base de Datos de Encuentro";
            # code...
        }

        else {
            echo    "No estamos conectados a la Base de Datos";
            # code...
        }

    $fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
    $tiempo=$_POST['tiempo'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO fecha (idfecha, fecha) VALUES ('', '$fecha')";

    if (mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) {
        echo    "Repertorio consolidado correctamente";
    }    else {
        echo    "No se consolidó la información";
    }
?>
```

Por otro lado, como puedo poner en un formulario por defecto en una lista desplegable el ultimo registro de la base de datos.
El link para el acceso es: https://minencuentro.000webhostapp.com/armar.html

Comment: Hola. No publiques tus credenciales reales de conexión. En cuanto al error, verifica en el log de errores por qué no inserta. Si no sabes cómo revisar el log de errores te recomiendo que no tardes en aprender a usar esa valiosa herramienta de depuración, mientras puedes poner el mensaje del `else`  así: `echo    "No se consolidó la información: ".$conexion->error;` Así podrás ver con exactitud el motivo del error.

Comment: Ya pude solucionarlo, tenía que obviar el id ya que en la db está autoincrement.

Comment: Lo hayas solucionado o no: ¡expusiste tus credenciales a toda la red! Le diste de comer a los bots :)

Comment: Gracias Padaleiana, ya en seguida cambio la clave de la base de datos, estoy empezando en esto. jejejeje

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya pude solucionarlo, tenía que obviar el id ya que en la db está autoincrement.